# Combining data from multiple sheets into one sheet using Openpyxl append

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I tried to make an algorithm which could merge data from two or more excel files to a new excel file, it does the job, but the output is not as expected.

[this image shows the output generated by the algorithm.] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ErHz.png)
[this is how the output should be.] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKlDZ.png)

```py
import os
import openpyxl

# Prompt the user to enter the directory location of the Excel files
directory_path = input("Enter the directory location of the Excel files: ")

# Check if the directory exists
if not os.path.exists(directory_path):
    print("Directory does not exist!")
    exit()

# Get a list of all files in the directory
file_list = os.listdir(directory_path)

# Filter only Excel files
excel_files = []
for file in file_list:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx') or file.endswith('.xls'):
        excel_files.append(file)

# Display the available file names
print("Excel files found within the given directory:")
count = 1
for file in excel_files:
    file_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    print(f"{count}) {file_name}")
    count += 1

# Prompt the user to select the files to add to the new file
selected_files = input("Select the file(s) that you want to add to the new file (separated by commas): ")
selected_files = selected_files.split(",")

# Store the selected file names
selected_file_names = []
print("\nSelected files:")
for file_index in selected_files:
    file_index = int(file_index.strip()) - 1  # Convert to integer and subtract 1 to get the index
    if file_index < 0 or file_index >= len(excel_files):
        print(f"Invalid file number: {file_index + 1}")
        continue
    selected_file = excel_files[file_index]
    selected_file_names.append(selected_file)
    print(selected_file)

# Create an empty dictionary to store the selected titles for each file
selected_titles_dict = {}

# Iterate over the selected files and display their titles
print("\nViewing the titles within the selected files...")
for selected_file in selected_file_names:
    print(selected_file)
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(directory_path, selected_file))
    sheet = wb.active

    titles = []
    for i, cell in enumerate(sheet[1], start=1):
        titles.append(cell.value)
        print(f"{i}) {cell.value}")

    # Prompt the user to select the titles to save to the new Excel file
    selected_titles = input("Select the titles of which you want to save the details (separated by commas): ")
    selected_titles = selected_titles.split(",")
    selected_titles = [int(title.strip()) - 1 for title in selected_titles]  # Convert to integer and subtract 1

    # Store the selected titles for the current file
    selected_titles_dict[selected_file] = selected_titles

    wb.close()

# Print the overall selected files and titles
print("\nOverall, you have selected the following:")
for selected_file in selected_file_names:
    print(f"\n{selected_file} - ", end="")
    selected_titles = selected_titles_dict[selected_file]
    for title_index in selected_titles:
        print(titles[title_index], end=", ")
    print()

# Prompt the user to confirm merging the data into a new Excel file
merge_data = input("\nDo you want to merge those data and write to a new Excel file? (y/n): ")
if merge_data.lower() != "y":
    print("Data merging cancelled.")
    exit()

# Prompt the user for the name of the new Excel file
new_file_name = input("\nProvide the name for the new Excel file: ")
new_file_name += ".xlsx"

# Prompt the user for the location to store the new file
new_file_location = input("Where do you want to store the newly created file?: ")

# Create a new workbook to store the merged data
new_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
new_sheet = new_wb.active

# Write the headers to the new file
header_row = []
for selected_file in selected_file_names:
    selected_titles = selected_titles_dict[selected_file]
    for title_index in selected_titles:
        header_row.append(titles[title_index])

new_sheet.append(header_row)

# Iterate over the selected files and write their data to the new file
for selected_file in selected_file_names:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(directory_path, selected_file))
    sheet = wb.active

    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
        data_row = []
        selected_titles = selected_titles_dict[selected_file]
        for title_index in selected_titles:
            data_row.append(row[title_index])
        new_sheet.append(data_row)

    wb.close()

# Save the new file
new_file_path = os.path.join(new_file_location, new_file_name)
new_wb.save(new_file_path)
new_wb.close()

print("\nData written to", new_file_name)

# enter the directory location of the Excel files : C:\Users\judej\Documents\kidaProject

# Excel files found within the given directory :
# 1) mad assignment.xlsx
# 2) wad assignment.xlsx
# 3) foss assignment.xlsx
# 4) dro assignment.xlsx

# select the file that you want to add to the new file (separated by commas) : 2 , 3

# selected files:
# wad assignment.xlsx
# foss assignment.xlsx
#
# viewing the titles within the selected files...
# wad assignment.xlsx
# 1) Reg.no
# 2) Name
# 3) Assignment Marks
#
# select the titles of which you want to save the details to a new Excel file (separated by commas) : 1,2,3

# You have selected Reg.no, Name, Assignment Marks from wad assignment.xlsx
# viewing foss assignment.xlsx
# 1) Reg.no
# 2) Name
# 3) Assignment Marks
#
# select the titles of which you want to save the details to a new Excel file (separated by commas) : 3

# You have selected Assignment Marks from foss assignment.xlsx
#
# overall you have selected the following:
#
# wad assignment.xlsx - Reg.no, Name, Assignment Marks
# foss assignment.xlsx - Assignment Marks
#
# do you want to merge those data and write to a new Excel file? (y/n): y

# Provide the name for the new Excel file : newGeneratedFile

# where do you want to store the newly created file? : C:\Users\judej\Documents\kidaProject

# writing data to newGeneratedFile.xlsx
```

I tried going through the code again and again and I couldn't spot the problem, maybe I am not capable of doing so at this level.

Comment: Your data in the screenshots were not clear enough, there are missing data in your first screenshot compared to the second one, why is that?. It's better if you can provide sample excel files (just a few rows is enough).

Comment: Looks to me your main issue is this; You are using append to copy the values from the orig sheet to the new workbook sheet for all input workbook/sheets. Openpyxl append does just that, it appends to the end of the sheet every time. Example:-  On Input Sheet 1 you have 2 columns and 2 rows then these are successfully added to your new workbook/sheet. Then on  Input Sheet 2 you have the same. The first append is not going to start adding from row 2 column 3, its going to append to the end of the sheet at the row after the last row added, i.e. A4 assuming you included Headers.

Comment: This is why in your example screenshot showing what you get rather than what you expect, you see the entries `98` and `56` in row 22 i.e. cells A22 & B22 rather than cells `E2` & `F2`. The first sheet last row is row 21 and the next append is always going to be on row 22 starting at column A. You will have to add all the data for a row into the list `data_row` before the append or the rest of the sheets to be added after the first cannot be done using `append`.

Comment: The title is .... not very helpful.

Comment: @Long, Thomas_Weller Thank you for your concern! actually the data in the Excel sheets doesn't matter. all I wanted was that any data I provide should be merged next to the previous data. Thanks anyway! Thank you for trying.

Comment: @moken , Thank you sir! I really appreciate it! Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a change to your code to show an option to work around your issue.

In the section that creates the list `data_row` I have changed this to a dictionary of lists keyed on the row number called `data_dict_row`.
The changed code first reads all the input sheets for all workbooks and updates this dictionary with all values to be written to the [key] row. The key is used to ensure the data from each sheet is added to the correct list in `data_dict_row`.
Therefore for the example sheet screenshot showing the incorrect result, the dictionary would have;

```
2: [TRI/IT/2020/F/0001, S.Dilshikka, 98, 0, 98, 56]
3: [TRI/IT/2020/F/0002, M.Jude, 99, 21, 99, 69]
```

for rows 2 & 3.
After the dictionary is created with all the values, then the new workbook/worksheet is created and `data_dict_row` is looped to obtain each list for each row which can then be appended on the new sheet (along with the Headers being the first append).

```py
import os
import openpyxl

# Prompt the user to enter the directory location of the Excel files
directory_path = input("Enter the directory location of the Excel files: ")

# Check if the directory exists
if not os.path.exists(directory_path):
    print("Directory does not exist!")
    exit()

# Get a list of all files in the directory
file_list = os.listdir(directory_path)

# Filter only Excel files
excel_files = []
for file in file_list:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx') or file.endswith('.xls'):
        excel_files.append(file)

# Display the available file names
print("Excel files found within the given directory:")
count = 1
for file in excel_files:
    file_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    print(f"{count}) {file_name}")
    count += 1

# Prompt the user to select the files to add to the new file
selected_files = input("Select the file(s) that you want to add to the new file (separated by commas): ")
selected_files = selected_files.split(",")

# Store the selected file names
selected_file_names = []
print("\nSelected files:")
for file_index in selected_files:
    file_index = int(file_index.strip()) - 1  # Convert to integer and subtract 1 to get the index
    if file_index < 0 or file_index >= len(excel_files):
        print(f"Invalid file number: {file_index + 1}")
        continue
    selected_file = excel_files[file_index]
    selected_file_names.append(selected_file)
    print(selected_file)

# Create an empty dictionary to store the selected titles for each file
selected_titles_dict = {}

# Iterate over the selected files and display their titles
print("\nViewing the titles within the selected files...")
for selected_file in selected_file_names:
    print(selected_file)
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(directory_path, selected_file))
    sheet = wb.active

    titles = []
    for i, cell in enumerate(sheet[1], start=1):
        titles.append(cell.value)
        print(f"{i}) {cell.value}")

    # Prompt the user to select the titles to save to the new Excel file
    selected_titles = input("Select the titles of which you want to save the details (separated by commas): ")
    selected_titles = selected_titles.split(",")
    selected_titles = [int(title.strip()) - 1 for title in selected_titles]  # Convert to integer and subtract 1

    # Store the selected titles for the current file
    selected_titles_dict[selected_file] = selected_titles


# Print the overall selected files and titles
print("\nOverall, you have selected the following:")
for selected_file in selected_file_names:
    print(f"\n{selected_file} - ", end="")
    selected_titles = selected_titles_dict[selected_file]
    for title_index in selected_titles:
        print(titles[title_index], end=", ")
    print()

# Prompt the user to confirm merging the data into a new Excel file
merge_data = input("\nDo you want to merge those data and write to a new Excel file? (y/n): ")
if merge_data.lower() != "y":
    print("Data merging cancelled.")
    exit()

# Prompt the user for the name of the new Excel file
new_file_name = input("\nProvide the name for the new Excel file: ")
new_file_name += ".xlsx"

# Prompt the user for the location to store the new file
new_file_location = input("Where do you want to store the newly created file?: ")

# Write the headers to the new file
header_row = []
for selected_file in selected_file_names:
    selected_titles = selected_titles_dict[selected_file]
    for title_index in selected_titles:
        header_row.append(titles[title_index])


# Iterate over the selected files and write their data to the new file
data_dict_row = {}
for selected_file in selected_file_names:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(directory_path, selected_file))
    sheet = wb.active

    ### Create dictionary of lists; key is the row number and value is all
    ### values from all sheets to be written that row
    row_num = 2
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=row_num, values_only=True):
        selected_titles = selected_titles_dict[selected_file]
        for title_index in selected_titles:
            if row_num not in data_dict_row:
                data_dict_row[row_num] = [row[title_index]]
            else:
                data_dict_row[row_num] += [row[title_index]]

        row_num += 1
    wb.close()

### Create a new workbook to store the merged data
new_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
new_sheet = new_wb.active
new_sheet.append(header_row)

### Loop through data_dict_rows for each row list
for new_sheet_row, data_row in data_dict_row.items():
    new_sheet.append(data_row)

# Save the new file
new_file_path = os.path.join(new_file_location, new_file_name)
new_wb.save(new_file_path)

print("\nData written to", new_file_name)
```

Example output
[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: Wow, Tank you so much! it woks like a charm.

Comment: Thank you for spending some time for me! Really appreciate it.

Comment: I'll just add this note, your code inlcudes the line `if file.endswith('.xlsx') or file.endswith('.xls'):` , Openpyxl only supports `xlsx` files, Excel 2007 and later. An `xls` file will error if you try to open it with Openpyxl.